# SSIS include GnuPG encryption over SQL Server agent job

Tags: encryption, ssis, gnupg, pgp, sql-agent-job

I have SSIS Package that have some process to export files, encrypt them using GnuPG and finally upload them. The package works fine in Visual Studio, but it fails when I add it to a SQL Server agent job and schedule to run.

I get the following error message:

> gpg: "The key name" : skipped: No public key
>
> gpg: "The Exported file path": encryption failed: No public key

I have another key that I added about two months ago, and it worked fine. The new key just works in Visual Studio, but does not work in the SQL agent job.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you run Visual Studio under your normal user account, but the SQL server calling GnuPG is running as a different system user.  GnuPG manages per-user keyrings. Make sure to import the key in the proper user's context.